# How to send ros2 messages from a websocket server to connected clients in tornado

Tags: multithreading, websocket, tornado, ros, ros2

I have a ros2 publisher script that sends custom messages from ros2 nodes. What I need to do is to have a subscriber (which is also my websocket server) to listen to the message that the pulisher sends then convert it to a dictionary and send it as a json from the websocket server to a connected websocket client. I have already checked the rosbridge repo but I could not make it work. It doesn't have enough documentation and I am new to ros.
I need something like this:

```
import rclpy
import sys
from rclpy.node import Node
import tornado.ioloop

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
import threading

from custom.msg import CustomMsg


from .convert import message_to_ordereddict





wss = []
class wsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'Online'
        if self not in wss:
            wss.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'Offline'
        if self in wss:
            wss.remove(self)

def wsSend(message):
    for ws in wss:
        ws.write_message(message)


class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_subscriber')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(CustomMsg, 'topic', self.CustomMsg_callback, 10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

    def CustomMsg_callback(self, msg):
        ws_message = message_to_ordereddict(msg)
        wsSend(ws_message)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado.web.Application(wsHandler))
    http_server.listen(8888)
    main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    # Start main loop
    main_loop.start()
```

so the callback function in MinimalSubscriber class, receives the ros message, converts it to dictionary and sends it to websocket client. I am a bit confused how to make these two threads (ros and websocket) to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I got a bit confused myself going through the threading. So I changed my approach and made it work using the tornado periodic callback and the `spin_once` function of rclpy as the callback function. I would post my solution as it might help some people who has the same issue.

```
import queue
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import tornado.ioloop

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web


from custom.msg import CustomMsg


from .convert import message_to_ordereddict





wss = []
class wsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    @classmethod
    def route_urls(cls):
        return [(r'/',cls, {}),]

    def open(self):
        print 'Online'
        if self not in wss:
            wss.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'Offline'
        if self in wss:
            wss.remove(self)


def make_app():
    myWebHandler = wsHandler.route_urls()
    return tornado.web.Application(myWebHandler)


message_queue = queue.Queue
class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_subscriber')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(CustomMsg, 'topic', self.CustomMsg_callback, 10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

    def CustomMsg_callback(self, msg):
        msg_dict = message_to_ordereddict(msg)
        msg_queue.put(msg_dict)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()


    def send_ros_to_clients():
        rclpy.spin_once(minimal_subscriber)
        my_msg = msg_queue.get()

        for client in ws_clients:
            client.write_message(my_msg)


    app = make_app()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(send_ros_to_clients, 1).start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()



    minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

I also implemented the `wsSend` function into the `send_ros_to_clients` function. Some might say that using a global queue is not the best practice but I could not come up with another solution. I would appreciate any suggestions or corrections on my solution.